# global name 'GLib2Reactor' is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, upnp

I'm struggling to get some python code using the python-brisa framework to work, the code is not written by me but should be straight forward.

```
    from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor
reactor = install_default_reactor()

from brisa.core.threaded_call import run_async_function

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from time import sleep

import sys, os

import sonos
import knx
```

Howewer after installing the frameworks I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knxsonos.py", line 24, in <module>
    reactor = install_default_reactor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/brisa/core/reactors/__init__.py", line 14, in install_default_reactor
    return GLib2Reactor()
NameError: global name 'GLib2Reactor' is not defined
```

I have been looking both stack overflow, and googling for days without finding a solution.

Anyone??, help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Looks like your install is busted. It seems highly unlikely that a bug in your code would cause that error.

Comment: Perfect, did a fresh install and everything is working

Answer (score 1):

Here's some possibilities:

- **GLib2Reactor doesn't return anything** - Then your code is wrong
- **GLib2Reactor is not declared** - try this:

  `x = GLib2Reactor()`
  `return x`
- **GLib2Reactor has to be imported** - just import it

**my best advice:** read the docs

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this problem on an Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) system, it was caused by `import gobject` failing.  The fix was to install the correct package:

`sudo apt-get install python-gobject-2`

This package is marked as deprecated, so on newer distributions it might be necessary to install the `python-gi` package instead, and then modify the callers to use the new names:

`from gi.repository import GObject`